# Do C blocks have a destructor?

Tags: objective-c-blocks

The clang block extension allows blocks to be used in C, C++ and Obj-C. When using blocks in C, there is no automatic memory management. So if a block references dynamic memory (pointer to a malloc'ed string for example), it's up to me to make sure that this string stays alive for as long as the block stays alive and may still want to access it. To manage the memory of the block itself, I can use `Block_copy()` and `Block_release()` but I cannot know for sure if `Block_release()` actually really releases a block or just decreases a reference counter to it. Is there a way to be informed if a block is getting destroyed so that I can then perform clean up of any dynamic memory that was used by the block code?

Comment: Even in Objective-C, wouldn't you have the same problem? i.e. if a block in Objective-C captures a pointer to malloc'd memory, you would still have no way of knowing when the block is destroyed, and no way of specifying a cleanup action to be performed when the block is destroyed.

Comment: @newacct What you say is correct, but in Obj-C I can use objects, so instead of malloc'ed memory, I can use `NSMutableData` which allows raw access to its internal memory block. Yet having a retain count, the block can keep it alive and release it when the block is released (no matter if the block ever ran at all or not). Whether the data will get destructed or not depends on the fact if code outside the block has still retained or not. If not retained, destroying the block will for sure destroy the data as well.